# Babel with NodeJS not working spread operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm using Babel (7.5.0) and NodeJS latest (12.x), so the spread operator is already handled by NodeJS and I don't want babel to mess with it.

This is my .babelrc :

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ],
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "modules": "commonjs",
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                },
                "useBuiltIns": "usage"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

This is my error :

```
ERROR in ./src/utils/logger/logger.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown helper objectSpread2
    at loadHelper (/app/node_modules/@babel/helpers/lib/index.js:238:27)
    at Object.getDependencies (/app/node_modules/@babel/helpers/lib/index.js:279:21)
    at File.addHelper (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js:204:33)
    at PluginPass.addHelper (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/plugin-pass.js:31:22)
    at PluginPass.ObjectExpression (/app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js:379:25)
    at newFn (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:193:21)
    at NodePath._call (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:85:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:144:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:94:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:95:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:85:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:144:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:94:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:95:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:90:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:146:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:94:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:95:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:85:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:144:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:94:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:95:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
 @ ./src/app.js 5:0-40
 @ multi ./src/app.js
```

I've read that I need to install some plugin, but I think that's for older nodejs versions, I don't see why I need a plugin for a feature built-in nodejs.

How can I do that?

**Update:**

I created an issue there : https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/798

Comment: this plugin `"transform-object-rest-spread"` enables spread operator. I am not sure if some feature is already built in then why we have to use some plugin to use that feature.

Comment: Do I have to use this plugin? Even with NodeJS 12.x ?

Comment: I am not sure. I didn't check it. let me dig into it and I will add a comment about my findings here.

Comment: I can successfully use `spread` operator in node version `v10.16.0`.

Comment: So you mean that it does not work with Node `v12.x` but works fine with `v10.16.0`?

Comment: Why are you using Babel with Node at all? Just write the code that you plan to use. Transpiling should not be needed.

Comment: @Intervalia to use `import` `export` modules syntax

Answer (score 7):

Babel maintainer here.

We have a bug in v7.5.0 (it will soon be fixed in v7.5.1). You have two possible workaround:

1. Run `npm install @babel/helpers` (or with yarn): this will force npm to download `@babel/helpers` v7.5.0, which contains the missing helper.
   If you are also using `@babel/transform-runtime`, make usre that `@babel/runtime` is v7.5.0
2. If you are using yarn, you can lock `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` to an older version which isn't affected by the issue. Add this code to your package.json:

   ```
   "resolutions": {
     "**/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.4.4"
   }
   ```

**EDIT** This should be fixed in v7.5.1, please update

Comment: Love finding an SO answer from 7 minutes ago for a problem I've been fighting for 30 minutes :).

Comment: I've tried installing @babel/helpers but to no avail, I just get a different version of the spreadoperator2 being called. Now I get `'@babel/runtime/helpers/objectSpread2' does not exist`, which implies it's looking for it in runtime not helpers.

Comment: @jQwierdy It looks like you found another bug with that helper (Babel should know that it isn't in `@babel/runtime` and inject it inline). I'll update my answer.

Comment: This should have been fixed in v7.5.1. There is another known bug which isn't fixed yet (the runtime helper doesn't work in older browsers without a polyfill for getOwnPropertyDescriptors)

Comment: @Nicolò so what's solution for `ReferenceError: _objectSpread is not defined`?

Comment: @Nicolò I'm using this with `babel-loader` and `webpack` 3.x, still having the same issue after updating to the newest versions